# debugging android tools code under windows.

Tags: android, debugging, debug-symbols, aapt

There is a crash bug in the aapt tool that happens till R12 (checked).
i'll give more details later, but for my question:
The bug happens on windows system, not on linux, it's not related to eclipse, i tried from the command line as well.
I want to debug the appt process under windows, will adding -g to the building fags in the android build tree (i'm using the trunk) solve the problem ? i want to see where the crash is and see if i can fix it but assembly code wont help me much and it doesn't reproduce on linux machines so i can't debug it in it's natural env.
(the tools are compiled for windows under linux using mingw32 library for linux, using sdk product with '_sdk_win' ).

Regardig the bug itself:

1. open an Android project under eclipse and call it 'a'
2. open the 'a' properties and check the 'Is Library' check box.
3. open another Android project and name it 'b'.
4. open it's properties and add 'a' as an android library it uses.
5. open the android plugin preferences and change the build from silent to verbose
6. clean both projects.
7. on linux everything is neat, on windows it crashes after the line:'baseFile zd has flavor (null)' which according to linux should be:'baseFile 0 has flavor ,,,,,,,,,,,hdpi,,,,,,,'
   most chances null pointer exception occurs here, the question is why only on windows ?

Comment: i just compiled aapt for windows from the trunk and the bug is gone, so i guess next SDK version will be better :-)

Comment: Please add your answer and set it so the question gets removed from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is gone from the next version (compiled from the trunk).